# Zero Percent of 100

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the equation:

$$5 \times 100 / 1$$

You see that $5$ over $1$ is a $500\%$ increase.  How would I show the percent of increase over zero?  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question.  I am just asking if it is possible to show a percent of increase over zero.  I see that I cannot divide by zero, so is it not possible?

Comment: If originally you had zero piece of something, then you get 2 of these something, then the increase is $\infty\%$. Is it what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm asking.  It's hard for me to understand "infinite %."  Aren't zero and one only one digit from each other?  How can 0 be infinite % from 5 when 1 is 500% from 5?

Comment: Question: 5 is what percent increase over 0 ?  This is a division problem with divisor 0.  Not allowed.  Any percent increase of zero is still zero.  Sometimes a guy I know (who is a volunteer worker, unpaid)  says "I want a raise" and the boss says "I'll double your salary" and we all laugh.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me understand :)

Comment: I would say 5 over 1 is a 400% increase.  Certainly 1 over 1 is no increase at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$500$% increase means that provided that you previously had $x$ amount of something, then it became $5$ times itself.

$500$% increase 'over $0$' thus means that you had $x=0$, and finally it became $5x$ which is still $0$.

Increase from $0$, hence is not measured well by the *ratio* of increasement, but the increasement itself. And, percentage can describe only *ratios*.

Comment: Question, and this is me speaking as a German, thus not 100% familiar with the English language:  Wouldn't a 500% increase mean something goes from 1 -> 6? It's increased by 5, which is 500% of the original value. I would understand if someone says "we performed 5 times better", but increased by 4 times.